# How to eliminate lines from a file while comparing two files

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two files, I need an output file which contains everything that is not in the first file but is in the second file, the second file contains everything that is in the first file with some more entries.
I tried:

```
for j in `cat first`; do sed '/"$j"/d' second; done
```

```
cat first 
a
b
c
d
e
f
# cat second
a
1
b
22
33
c
44
d
11
e
44
f
```

Comment: Use `grep -vFxf first second`

Comment: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds several issues with the code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this `grep`:

```sh
grep -vFxf first second

1
22
33
44
11
```

Options are:

- `-v`: Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns
- `-F`: Fixed string search
- `-x`: Exact match
- `-f`: Use a file for patterns

Comment: did not know grep could be used like comm! this is great

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the answer from @anubhava, it's great for scripting.
However, if you'd just like visual aid to see the difference between two files the good old diff command can be a great help.

```
$  diff -y first second
a                               a
                                  > 1
b                               b
                                  > 22
                                  > 33
c                               c
                                  > 44
d                               d
                                  > 11
e                               e
                                  > 44
f                               f
```

-y, or --side-by-side, output in two columns.

I've seen this great one as well (full credit to @Kent):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next;}!($0 in a)' first second
1
22
33
44
11
44
```

There's more commands like these:

- colordiff - like diff but with color
- cmp - compare files bytewise
- vimdiff - diff using the vim editor

There's probably lots of other great ways to do this, these are just some of the ways.

Comment: Yes, that's the straightforward awk solution.

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava's comment is a great answer.

With comm, ignore what unique to first, and ignore what's common

```
comm --nocheck-order -13 first second
```

There's a straightforward [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution too.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1 : ultra truncated edition

```
mawk ' NR==FNR { __[$_] } NF -= $_ in __' FS='^$' 
                                          test_first_file.txt 
                                          test_second_file.txt
    1
    22
    33
    44
    11
    44
```

————————————————————————————————

```
[m/n/g]awk '
BEGIN { FS="^$" } NR==1 { 
   do { __[$-_] } while ((getline)<=(FNR==NR))

} ($-_ in __)!=!___[$-_]-- ' test_first_file.txt test_second_file.txt
```

————————————————————————————————

```
1
22
33
44
11
```

Comment: Rather needlessly esoteric IMO.

Comment: that's only cuz i didn't want it to print out duplicates. if that and nawk are not concerns, then I could truncate it all the way to mawk ' _^(FNR<NR) { __[$_] } _^($_ in __)' FS='^$'   test_first_file.txt test_second_file.txt

Comment: The `__` array could use a "real" variable name. I've never seen `$-_` -- what is that? You're relatively new to SO, you'll find that "golf" answers are not particularly appreciated.

Comment: " _ " was never defined, so it's an empty string — any empty string evaluates to boolean false in awk, meaning numeric zero, so $_ is just $0. $-_ is only for nawk cuz it complaints about empty field, so $-_ is just to force it to evaluate numerically, " $-_ " >>>> "$-0" >>>> $0. You can do $+_ it's the same thing. you can even do $-OFMT or $+SUBSEP and it'll give you $0. try it yourself.

Comment: @glenn jackman : and how does calling it a[ 2 ] be any different ? it provides just as little useful info as __[ 2 ]

Comment: You have to think about your audience when providing answers. If someone's asking "How do I do (something that an expert thinks is obvious)", showing off with brainf*ck looking code is unlikely to help anyone.

Comment: @glenn jackman : and you think it's helping anyone at all by spoon feeding them everything ? if they're keen to learn, i'm more than willing to explain, but I'm not here to do someone else's homework for them

Comment: So downvote the question and move on. Why bother answering at all? I do appreciate the explanation to me question BTW.